# Protecting the argument of a command from the effect of the command

Tags: macros

How can I "protect" an argument of a command from the effect of the command?

The link is interrupted by `\spacedallcaps`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\spacedallcaps{\href{http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale}{test}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\textbf{\textnormal{normal} boldface}`; please, make the title of this question to reflect the exact topic you're discussing.

Comment: In general? You need to know what a command does to be able to counteract what it does or to know you can't do anything. Every command is different...

Comment: In general, setting it first in a box would remove any formatting from impacting it. However, depending on the use, it might also not fit well with the rest of the text, removing any inter-word shrink/stretch.

Comment: @Werner `\unhbox` should avoid this issue, no?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but wouldn't be easier to make TeX transform `\xswitch\textbf{{normal} bold}` into `{normal}\textbf{ bold}`? I'm sure such `\xswitch` command can be (quite easily) designed.

Comment: @cgnieder I have update the question

Comment: Why not `\href{http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale}{\spacedallcaps{test}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only `test` in spaced capital letters, obviously

```
\href{http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale}{\spacedallcaps{test}}
```

is the answer.

But if you want to make a chapter title into a link (`classicthesis` uses `\spacedallcaps` in that case, if I remember correctly), then you have to resort to a hack:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\newcommand\mytemp{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\renewcommand\mytemp{http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale}
\chapter[test]{\href{\noexpand\mytemp}{test}}
\end{document}
```

The problem is not to show the link address to `\MakeUppercase` that would turn it in uppercase too.

However I don't recommend turning a chapter title into a link; better putting the link just at the start of the chapter text.